# Java Client-Server Cant get the Server to keep sending the right information

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, server, client

I am currently making a Client-Server program that has the client continuously make a list of 5 random integers and then sends it to the client and keeps repeating this until I tell it to stop.

The server will take the list from the client and find out which numbers are prime, put the primes into a new list and then sends it off the client, repeating it as long as the Client is sending the lists.

Heres the Client code:

```
public class Client2 {
    static boolean isRunning = false;


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Running Client");

    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 6789);
    ObjectOutputStream toServer = 
            new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    toServer.flush();

    ObjectInputStream inFromServer = 
            new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

    Random randint = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter “!” to startand stop, “#” to quit:");

    if(input.nextLine().equals("!")) {
        isRunning = true;
    }

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(isRunning) {
                List<Integer> randList = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
                //Makes the Random List
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    int num = randint.nextInt(98)+2;
                    randList.add(num);
                }

                //Sleeps the thread
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Writes the list
                try {
                    toServer.writeObject(randList);
                    toServer.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Send: " + randList);

                try {
                    System.out.println("Received: " + inFromServer.readObject());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }//End while loop   
            }   
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                if(input.nextLine().equals("!")) {
                    t.suspend();
                    System.out.println("Sleeping");
                }
                if(input.nextLine().equals("!")) {
                    t.resume();
                    System.out.println("Resuming");
                }   
            }

            }

    }); 
    t.start();
    t2.start();

}
}
```

And heres the Server Code:

```
public class Server {
    static List clientNums = new ArrayList();
    static List primes = new ArrayList();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



    System.out.println("Running Server");
    ServerSocket welcome = new ServerSocket(6789);

    Socket connectionSocket = welcome.accept();
    System.out.println("Connected");

    ObjectInputStream inFromClient = 
            new ObjectInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());

    ObjectOutputStream toClient = 
            new ObjectOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
    toClient.flush();

    while(true) {
        clientNums = (ArrayList) inFromClient.readObject();
        System.out.println("Client list: " + clientNums);

        for(int i = 0; i < clientNums.size(); i++) {
            if(isPrime((int) clientNums.get(i))) {
                primes.add(clientNums.get(i));
            }
        }//End for loop

        System.out.println("Received: " + primes);
        toClient.writeObject(primes);
        primes.clear();
    }//End while loop
}//End main
public static boolean isPrime(int n) { //CITE: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/
    for(int i=2;2*i<=n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;

  }
}
```

Now everything works how I want it to...EXCEPT the fact the when the client sends the first list, it will receive back the first list of primes correctly. But for the second list and beyond, it continues to just receive the first list of primes instead of the new list; Even thought the server is still receiving and making a list of primes correctly. I've been stumped on this for a bit. Can anyone help out?

Heres the output for the client:

```
Running Client
Enter “!” to startand stop, “#” to quit:
!
Send: [63, 63, 64, 4, 53]
Received: [53]
Send: [43, 6, 70, 67, 69]
Received: [53]
Send: [2, 29, 83, 45, 67]
Received: [53]
```

And output for the Server:

```
Running Server
Connected
Client list: [63, 63, 64, 4, 53]
Received: [53]
Client list: [43, 6, 70, 67, 69]
Received: [43, 67]
Client list: [2, 29, 83, 45, 67]
Received: [2, 29, 83, 67]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to investigate `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` or `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()`.

Comment: Should this be done on just the server or the client too?